# Implement a coordinator service for Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I want to implement a coordinator service which run in Namenode.

So that when a map task finished their tasks, it will send a feedback to namenode to inform that "Machine (x.x.x.x) has processed block ID... belong to file ...". Namenode will maintain these information in table (for example).

I know this kind of question too general but actually now I got stuck at this.

Can I implement this function in Hadoop and how can I do that? Anyone can give me ideals or some similar tasks have done before?

Comment: Namenode has audit logs about who opened which file path. With the file path then you know the block ids.

Comment: My target is how can I implement a feedback from data node to name node when a map task finished.  Is it possible?

Comment: no. HDFS is an independent project. You need to do this in your map reduce job.

Answer (score 0):

You need a service that receive the notification and store it in some place (may be a rest service or a MQ), it doesn´t matter if this service run on the NameNode or in a server outside the cluster. Just to say that the NameNode is the most critical point in the cluster, I really don´t recommend to use it to deploy any additional service.

Then, you will require to override the **cleanup** Map´s method to send the "map task completed" message after the Map task has finished.

Or you can try the Hadoop ResourceManager API to see if there is the information that you are looking for and just poll that API instead to create a new one.